# jQuery Datatables - retrieving information from other pages

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I have got a problem with getting information from jQuery datatable.
Here is the table:

[image: table]

I would like to get information stored in the table. I have tried to do this by this:

```
var languages=[];
var people=[];

$("select[name='languageID']").each(function(){
    languages.push( $(this).val() );
});

$("input:hidden[name='personID']").each(function(){
    people.push( $(this).val() );
});
```

but it is getting values from current chosen page. If I run this in the situation like on the screenshot, only values from page 2 would be pushed to the arrays. I have tried to check where values from page 1 are stored, but I could not find anything. I also looked for it on [jQuery datatables homepage](http://www.datatables.net/)

Could anyone help?

Regards

**EDIT:**

so I should do something like this:

```
table.column( 0 ).cache( 'search' ).each( function ( d ) { /*action here*/ } );
```

?

But what should be in action?

When I debug `table.column( 2 ).cache( 'search' );` I have got this:

```
[   choose language ", " choose language ", " choose language ", " choose language ", " choose language ", " choose language " ]
```

It is first option in "Chosen language" select. I think, that I need something, which would return html code from each cell in column, so that I can analyse it later.

Comment: What version? The api has changed recently.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This one turns out harder than expected. At first, I try using the datatable [`data()`](http://datatables.net/reference/api/data()) API, but that returns the dropdown lists as HTML strings, which are not very useful. Then I come across this [article](http://www.datatables.net/examples/api/form.html) on how datatable deals with form inputs. The trick is to recognize that your datatable object can retrieve nodes from within the document regardless of paging.

A live demo can be found on my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ivan_sim/rocog871/).

EDIT: As per discussion with OP, the following codes can be utilized instead of relying on embedded column selectors:

```
table.$('select[name="languageID"]').each(function(index, value{
    languages.push($(value).val());
});
```

Comment: I have posted answer to my own question, but thank you very much for help :)

Comment: @Hladeo Instead of embedding those column selectors in your codes, you can do just `table.$('select').each(function(){}...);`.

Comment: when I do `table.$('select[name="languageID"]').each(function(a){ languages.push( a ) });` than I have got indexes of all rows: `[ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ]`

Comment: @Hladeo Try with `table.$('select[name="languageID"]').each(function(index, value){ languages.push(value)});` I tested it in the jsfiddle; it should work.

Comment: almost correct. should be `languages.push( $(value).val() )` and than it works :)

Comment: You're right! Can I get an upvote on the answer? :-)

Answer (score 1):

In the [**legacy api**](http://legacy.datatables.net/ref), `fnGetData` should return what you need.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  oTable = $('#example').dataTable();

  oTable.$('#myButton').click( function () {
    var data = oTable.fnGetData( this );
    // ... do something with the array / object of data for the row
  } );
});
```

In the new api (v1.10+), you'll probably want `column().cache()`.

http://datatables.net/reference/api/column().cache()

Comment: +1 for help with `column()`, but `cache()` was not proper in my case

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I should modify my code to:

```
var languages=[];
var people=[];

table
  .column(0)
  .nodes()
  .each(function(a){
    people.push( $(a).find("input:hidden[name='personID']").val() );
});

table
  .column(2)
  .nodes()
  .each(function(a){
    languages.push( $(a).find("select[name='languageID']").val() );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

As @ivan.sim says, it's not so easy to get the full table data, although I finally [found a solution](https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/53519/finding-value-of-hidden-rows-data-only) which you can use to get values (including hidden inputs etc) from the full table including pages that are not displayed:

```
table.rows().every(function (rowIdx, tableLoop, rowLoop) {
    var data = this.node();
    console.log($(data).find('input').prop('checked'));
    console.log($(data).find('input[name=someField]').val());
});
```